# How to get a random component subgraph with given number of edges from the existing component graph?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I would like to make a component subgraph with edges from the existing component graph in networkx. Both graphs will be undirected.

For example, I want my new graph to have 100 edges from the existing one and be component. The existing one has about 2 million edges and is component.

My current approach is below:

```
def get_random_component(number_of_edges):
    G_def = nx.Graph()
    G_copy = nx.Graph()
    G_iter = nx.Graph()
    G_copy.add_edges_from(G.edges)
    
    for i in range(number_of_edges):
        G_iter.clear()
        G_iter.add_edges_from(G_copy.edges)
        currently_found_edge = random.choices(list(G_iter.edges), k=1)[0]
        while (G_def.has_edge(*currently_found_edge) or (not G_def.has_node(currently_found_edge[0])
                                                         and not G_def.has_node(currently_found_edge[1]))):
            G_iter.remove_edge(*currently_found_edge)
            currently_found_edge = random.choices(list(G_iter.edges), k=1)[0]
        G_def.add_edge(*currently_found_edge)
        G_copy.remove_edge(*currently_found_edge)
            
    return G_def
```

but it is very time-consuming. Is there a better way to find a random component subgraph with given number of edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  First, when you're asking for algorithm help, post your algorithm in an easily-readable form.  Code is fine, but only if you use meaningful variable names: `def`, `copy`, and `iter` don't mean much.

Your posted algorithm goes through a lot of failure pain in that `while` loop, especially with your given case of building a 100-edge component from a graph of 2e6 edges.  Unless the graph is *heavily* connected, you will spin a lot for each new edge.

Instead of flailing through the graph, *construct* a connected subgraph.  Let's call it SG.  Also, assume that `G` below is a copy of the original graph that we can mutate as desired.

```
new_node = a random node of G.
legal_move = new_node.edges()   # A set of edges you can traverse from nodes in SG
for _ in range(100):
    if legal_move is empty:
        # You have found a connected component
        #   with fewer than 100 edges.
        # SG is the closure of that component.
        # Break out of this loop, Subtract SG from G, and start over.
    new_edge = # a random edge from legal_move (see note below)
    subtract SG from legal_move (don't consider any edges already used).
    add new_edge to SG
    One node of new_edge is already in SG; if the other is not ...
        Add other node to SG
        Add other.edges to legal_move (except for new_edge)
```

*note on random choice*:

> You have to define your process for "random".  One simple way is to
> choose a random edge from `legal_moves`.  Another way is to choose a
> random node from those in `legal_moves`, and then choose a random edge
> from that node.  Your growth patterns will differ, depending on the
> degree of each node.

The process above will be much faster for most graphs.
Since each edge references both of its nodes, and each node maintains a list of its edges, the exploration and update phases will be notably faster.

Coding is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)